# Who sent the T-800 nicknamed "Pops"?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-genisys

In *Terminator Genisys*, who sent "Pops" to protect Sarah Connor?

When asked who sent him, the T-800 answers the records have been deleted so he doesn't know, and (I think) Reese speculates that whoever sent Sarah's guardian didn't want anyone else to know his/her identity.

Is it ever stated who this was, or was it left out for a possible sequel?

Comment: My proposal for the sequel is "Terminator: Geriatrics": a young Sarah Connor finds out she is at the same time Kyle Reese (after a sex change) and also a time travelling robot from the future, intent on killing James Cameron before he films his Avatar sequel. Ahnold plays a T-800 trapped in a home for elderly robots and doesn't do much.

Comment: I think they intentionally left the issue unclear, so it could be revealed in a sequel.

Comment: pops send himself to the past or a terminator he created himself. thats my idea. so the start and the end of terminator is terminator himself. shwatzeneger in this role have taken all the movie on his shoulder exept one, it is a reverence to him. maybe the terminator pops have a human conscience in him. like the movie ask the question few time to mutch for me (pics of sahra, drawing, father presence, even a question by rees etc...), so to the last end terminator can be good guy without skynet.

Comment: @Babelsteeve he can't be himself because he can age and this would make pops absorb that strange liquid over and over again, also regenerating is not an ability that he have at the beginning of the movie ¿?¿?¿?...

Comment: @Babelsteeve Your answer shouldn't be a comment (comments are for clarifications, nitpicks or short remarks). But if you change it into an answer, it will probably get downvoted to hell due to lack of references and too much speculation.

Comment: @Keen - Why does your bounty say "there won't be a sequel"? [Last I heard](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/93510/20151012/terminator-genisys-producer-says-franchise-not-on-hold-but-readjusting.htm) the production company, Skydance, claimed they were still planning a sequel but were delaying a bit to try to retool it in light of fan criticisms of Genisys. It's possible that's just an excuse to drop sequel plans without losing face, but in any case I doubt the writers would be permitted to reveal what they had planned as long as the official line was that a sequel was still happening.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Huh, news to me.

Comment: From sister site [Who sends Pops back in time in Terminator Genisys?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36170/who-sends-pops-back-in-time-in-terminator-genisys)

Comment: @TerryMcGinnis Thanks! Unfortunately the answers there are inconclusive :(

Comment: @AndresF. as we all know, a secret is kept inside the hearts of writers and after bad reception of movie nobody digging much to get it out.

Comment: @TerryMcGinnis Yup. And a well-deserved bad reception, too :P

Comment: @AndresF. now movies version have official words too https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/94565/1190

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Apparently the writers have an answer in mind, but left the reveal for the hoped-for sequel(s). See [this interview Q&A](http://io9.com/your-burning-questions-about-the-plot-of-terminator-gen-1715234003):

> **Who sent the Terminator back to 1973 to protect a young Sarah Connor?**
>
> This question is purposely left unanswered in the film, but would
>   potentially be answered in a sequel, if that happens. However, writers
>   Laeta Kalogridis and Patrick Lussier did confirm they know the answer.

edit: Looks like there [won't be any sequel to Genisys](http://deadline.com/2016/01/terminator-2-pulled-off-schedule-paramount-1201687034/) (unless the 'Terminator 2' that Paramount pulled from the schedule was actually [this 3D conversion](http://io9.gizmodo.com/hell-be-back-terminator-2-judgment-day-returns-to-thea-1748329814) rather than the Genisys sequel). Maybe the writers will reveal what they were originally planning in an interview or a comic or something.

Comment: I can't imagine a more definitive answer than this.  +1

Comment: Agreed. Disappointing, but Word of God trumps all.

Comment: Cannot wait for the answers